# how to import xml file into octobercms using kylp

Tags: php, xml, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to utilize this plugin to import an xml file, I have a simple xml file.

```
<MYData>
    <login_details>
        <unique_ref>1-61</unique_ref>
        <login_name>tomme</login_name>
        <login>me</login>
        <password>me</password>
        <file1>Test</file1>
        <file2/>
        <file3/>
        <file4/>
    </login_details>
    <login_details>
        <unique_ref>1-61</unique_ref>
       <login_name>tony</login_name>
        <login>tony</login>
        <password>tony</password>
        <file1>Test1</file1>
        <file2/>
        <file3/>
        <file4/>
    </login_details>
</MYData>
```

but can only manage to import 3 nodes I wrongly thought I could simply append this code `$postBlog = $blogPost::create(['unique_ref' => $item->unique_ref, 'slug' => Str::slug($item->unique_ref), 'login_name' => $item->login_name, 'login' =>$item->login);`but the last node does not update the database any help would be gratefully appreciated as I am new to coding in October frame work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this piece of code that works but my model requires the slug to have a value

```
foreach ($xmls->login_details as $row => $data) {
try {
if (!$refno_prop = array_get($data, 'refno_prop')) {
}
/*
* Find or create
*/
$post = Post::make();
if ($this->update_existing) {
$post = $this->findDuplicatePost($data) ?: $post;
}
$postExists = $post->exists;
/*
* Set attributes
*/
$except = ['id', 'categories', 'author_email'];

foreach (array_except($data, $except) as $attribute => $value) {
$post->{$attribute} = $value ?: null;
}
$post->forceSave();
/*
* Log results
*/
if ($postExists) {
$this->logUpdated();
}
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
$this->logError($row, $ex->getMessage());
}
}
```

so I am looking for a method to add the slug value from an existing node I also haven't figured out how to stop the same data from being added to the database